# What's a valid @MessagePattern for NestJS MQTT microservice?

Tags: node.js, typescript, microservices, mqtt, nestjs

I'm trying to setup a MQTT Microservice using NestJS according to [the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/mqtt).

I've started a working Mosquitto Broker using Docker and verified it's operability using various MQTT clients. Now, when I start the NestJS service it seems to be connecting correctly (mqqt.fx shows new client), yet I am unable to receive any messages in my controllers.
This is my bootstrapping, just like in the docs:

**main.ts**

```
async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(AppModule, {
        transport: Transport.MQTT,
        options: {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 1883,
            protocol: 'tcp'
        }
    });
    app.listen(() => console.log('Microservice is listening'));
}
bootstrap();
```

**app.controller.ts**

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {

    @MessagePattern('mytopic') // tried {cmd:'mytopic'} or {topic:'mytopic'}
    root(msg: Buffer) {
        console.log('received: ', msg)
    }
}
```

Am I using the message-pattern decorator wrongly or is my concept wrong of what a NestJS MQTT microservice even is supposed to do? I thought it might subscribe to the topic I pass to the decorator. My only other source of information being the corresponding [unit tests](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/microservices/test/server/server-mqtt.spec.ts)

Comment: This strange behavior was fixed in [Nest 7.0](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/releases/tag/v7.0.0). You can directly subscribe topic without any suffix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### nest.js Pattern Handler

On nest.js side we have the following pattern handler:

```
@MessagePattern('sum')
sum(data: number[]): number {
  return data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}
```

As [@Alexandre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54277108/4694994) explained, this will actually listen to `sum_ack`.

---

### Non-nest.js Client

A non-nest.js client could look like this (just save as client.js, run `npm install mqtt` and run the program with `node client.js`):

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost:1883')

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('sum_res', function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      client.publish('sum_ack', '{"data": [2, 3]}');
    }
  })
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  console.log(message.toString())
  client.end()
})
```

It sends a message on the topic `sum_ack` and listens to messages on `sum_res`. When it receives a message on `sum_res`, it logs the message and ends the program. nest.js expects the message format to be `{data: myData}` and then call the param handler `sum(myData)`.

```
// Log:
{"err":null,"response":5} // This is the response from sum()
{"isDisposed":true} // Internal "complete event" (according to unit test)
```

Of course, this is not very convenient...

---

### nest.js Client

That is because this is meant to be used with another nest.js client rather than a normal mqtt client. The nest.js client abstracts all the internal logic away. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54293468/4694994), which describes the client for redis (only two lines need to be changed for mqtt).

```
async onModuleInit() {
  await this.client.connect();
  // no 'sum_ack' or {data: [0, 2, 3]} needed
  this.client.send('sum', [0, 2, 3]).toPromise();
}
```

Comment: As you say it's not very convinient and a bit confusing. At first I was happy to see this build-in interface with MQTT or AMQP, but then I understood that it use request-response paradigm, and this is a bit strange for this kind of protocole.

Comment: Thanks very much for the clarification, like Alexandre pointed out, it kinda defeats the purpose when there's such a coupling to a specific client paradigm. Just glad I now know how it's supposed to be used

Comment: Does somebody use the clientMqtt class for publishing? I have the problem, that is publish not just the data - also the pattern and id. But I just need the data.

I use the ClientMqtt.send function.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is not very clear, but it seem that for mqtt if you have `@MessagePattern('mytopic')` you can publish a command on the topic `mytopic_ack` and you will get response on `mytopic_res`. I am still trying to find out how to publish to the mqtt broker from a service.

See https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/e019afa472c432ffe9e7330dc786539221652412/packages/microservices/server/server-mqtt.ts#L99

```
  public getAckQueueName(pattern: string): string {
    return `${pattern}_ack`;
  }

  public getResQueueName(pattern: string): string {
    return `${pattern}_res`;
  }
```

Comment: I have created an example on how to publish messages as a client in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54293468/4694994 Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

@Tanas is right. Nestjs/Microservice now listens to your $[topic] and answer to $[topic]/reply. The postfix _ack and _res  are deprecated.

For example:

```
  @MessagePattern('helloWorld')
  getHello(): string {
    console.log("hello world")
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
```

Listens now on Topic: ***helloWorld*** 
Replies now on Topic ***helloWorld/reply***

**Regarding ID**

You **should** also provide an id within the payload (See @Hakier) and Nestjs will reply with an answer, containing your id.
If you don't have any id, there still won't be any reply but the corresponding logic will still trigger.

For example (Using the snipped from above):
your msg:

```
{"data":"foo","id":"bar"}
```

Nestjs reply:

```
{"response":"Hello World!","isDisposed":true,"id":"bar"}
```

**Without ID:**

your message:

```
{"data":"foo"} or {}
```

*No reply* but *Hello World* in Terminal

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with MQTT today and this helped me a little, but I had more problems and below you can see my findings:

### Wrong way of configuration broker URL

In my case when I used non-local MQTT server I started with this:

```js
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(AppModule, {
    transport: Transport.MQTT,
    options: {
      host: 'test.mosquitto.org',
      port: 1883,
      protocol: 'tcp',
    },
  });
  await app.listenAsync();
```

but like you can read in a [constructor of ServerMqtt](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/107b243c8b7d00c428c4ab9740dad074ec4af89d/packages/microservices/server/server-mqtt.ts#L26) they use `url` option only (when not provided it fallbacks to [`'mqtt://localhost:1883'`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/8d367c415bdf175d0d86df55505c1207ec251d51/packages/microservices/constants.ts#L5). While I do not have local MQTT it will never resolve `app.listenAsync()` which is resolved only on [connect](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/107b243c8b7d00c428c4ab9740dad074ec4af89d/packages/microservices/server/server-mqtt.ts#L42) and will also not run any handler.

#### It started to work when I adjusted code to use `url` option.

```js
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(AppModule, {
    transport: Transport.MQTT,
    options: {
      url: 'mqtt://test.mosquitto.org:1883',
    },
  });
  await app.listenAsync();
```

### Messages require `id` property

Second very weird problem was that when I used **Non-nest.js Client** script from @KimKern I had to register two MessagePatterns: `sum` and `sum_ack`:

```js
  @MessagePattern('sum')
  sum(data: number[]): number {
    return data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  }

  @MessagePattern('sum_ack')
  sumAck(data: number[]): number {
    return data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  }
```

When I used `console.log` I discovered that the latter is being run but only when the first one is present. You can push the same message to the broker using mqtt cli tool to check it:

`mqtt pub -t 'sum_ack' -h 'test.mosquitto.org' -m '{"data":[1,2]}'`

But the biggest problem was that it **didn't reply (publish sum_res)**.

#### The solution was to provide also `id` while sending a message.

`mqtt pub -t 'sum_ack' -h 'test.mosquitto.org' -m '{"data":[1,2], "id":"any-id"}'`

Then we could remove 'sum_ack' MessagePattern and leave only this code:

```js
  @MessagePattern('sum')
  sum(data: number[]): number {
    return data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  }
```

The reason for this was hidden inside `handleMessage` method of ServerMqtt which will not [publish](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/107b243c8b7d00c428c4ab9740dad074ec4af89d/packages/microservices/server/server-mqtt.ts#L89) response from a handler if a message didn't have [`id`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/107b243c8b7d00c428c4ab9740dad074ec4af89d/packages/microservices/server/server-mqtt.ts#L75).

**TL/DR**
Specify url to message broker using `url` option only and always provide `id` for a message.

I hope that will save some time to others.

Happy hacking!