# Use socket client with NestJs microservice

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, microservices, nestjs

I started working with NestJs recently and got stock while trying to test my [NestJs microservices](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics) app using a [TCP client](https://packetsender.com/)

Is it possible to trigger an `@EventPattern` or `@MessagePattern()` using a non-nest app?

When trying this method the the socket client just stuck on `trying to connect`.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to connect a nest app to a non-nest client but you have to pay attention to the special handling of nest, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54294325/4694994

It's hard to tell what the connection issue is without seeing your setup. Can you post the relevant parts of your code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Update Feb 2020

Since nest v6.6.0, it has become easier to integrate external services with a message de/serializer. 
 Have a look at the corresponding [PR](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/2653).

---

## Original Answer

You have to set up the ports correctly to use it with nest:

The pattern you want to send is

```
<json-length>#{"pattern": <pattern-name>, "data": <your-data>[, "id": <message-id>]}
```

Example:

```
76#{"pattern":"sum","data":[0,3,3],"id":"ce51ebd3-32b1-4ae6-b7ef-e018126c4cc4"}
```

The parameter `id` is for `@MessagePattern`, without it `@EventPattern` will be triggered.

[image]

In your `main.ts` you setup the nest server. That's the port you want to send to from Packet Sender (enter at 1).

```
const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(AppModule, {
  transport: Transport.TCP,
  options: { host: 'localhost', port: 3005 },
  //                            ^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

Then you want your nest `@Client` to listen to messages coming from Packet Sender (see position 2 in image)

```
@Client({
  transport: Transport.TCP,
  options: { host: 'localhost', port: 52079 },
  //                            ^^^^^^^^^^^  
})
private client: ClientTCP;
```

Then connect your client:

```
async onModuleInit() {
  await this.client.connect();
}
```

and define a `@MessagePattern`:

```
@MessagePattern('sum')
sum(data: number[]): number {
  console.log(data);
  return data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}
```

As you can see, in the example I'm sending `[0,3,3]` and nest correctly responds with the sum `6`.

Comment: @kernkim the message structure was exactly what I needed.
by creating a massage `[MSG_LEN]#{ pattern: "[PATTERN_STRING]", data: "[DATA]" }` I'm able to send custom messages.

Thenks

Comment: I have checked this - it is exactly what I want it to do , but I can't get it to work. HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n .   I am using this sample https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/03-microservices - which seems 
to work for internal communication - but I can't connect with the service through packet sender.

Comment: @MartinThompson I don't have time to look into this atm, but there have been changes that should make it easier to integrate external services. Have a look at this pr: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/2653 If your problem persists, maybe open a new question so someone can have a look at it. :)

Comment: Thanks @KimKern . It was actually easier than I thought.  I just wasn't putting the correct pattern in:

Comment: It is:
89#{"pattern": { "cmd": "sum"  },"data":[0,3,3],"id":"ce51ebd3-32b1-4ae6-b7ef-e018126c4cc4"}

Comment: @KimKern Could you please elaborate more on your update? The PR is huge, and I don't quite grasp the idea.