# How to probe NestJS microservice health in TCP transport?

Tags: nestjs

Using the NestJS Terminus Microservice template: https://github.com/nestjs/terminus/tree/master/sample/002-microservice-app
The microservice starts successfully.

How do I call the health check controller method from outside?

I tried `echo "20#{\"pattern\":\"health\"}" | nc localhost 8889` (like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55630329/6517320) but Nest writes:

> ERROR [Server] There is no matching event handler defined in the remote service. Event pattern: "health".

Answer (score 0):

in case you wanna do the health check with an http call, you'd need a hybrid app that also listens to http requests